# Persistent error: Unresolved reference: runBlocking when using kotlinx-coroutines-core-js:1.7.3

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-multiplatform, kotlin-js, arrow-kt

I'm trying to use coroutines and the Arrow library function `parMapNotNull` to parallelize some code in a scientific computation library I'm working on. Everywhere I read, the function `kotlinx.coroutines.runBlocking` gets used and recommended for going from a serial, blocking code context to a coroutine code context.

However, I keep getting a compilation error

```
e: file:///Users/mik/IdeaProjects/tda4j/src/commonMain/kotlin/org/appliedtopology/tda4j/ParallelSymmetricSimplexIndexVietorisRips.kt:16:9 Unresolved reference: runBlocking
```

I am able to resolve the issue *specifically* for a JVM target, but even with imports of `kotlinx-coroutines-core-js`, I get unresolved reference for any JS compilation of the code.

My `build.gradle.kts` includes

```
    sourceSets {
        val commonMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.7.3")
                implementation("io.arrow-kt:arrow-core:1.2.1")
                implementation("io.arrow-kt:arrow-fx-coroutines:1.2.1")
                implementation("space.kscience:kmath-core:0.3.1")
                implementation("space.kscience:kmath-tensors:0.3.1")
            }
        }
        val commonTest by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation("io.kotest:kotest-framework-engine:5.7.2")
                implementation("io.kotest:kotest-assertions-core:5.7.2")
                implementation("io.kotest:kotest-property:5.7.2")
            }
        }
        val jvmMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core-jvm:1.7.3")
            }
        }
        val jvmTest by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation("io.kotest:kotest-runner-junit5:5.7.2")
            }
        }
        val jsMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core-js:1.7.3")
            }
        }
```

*Edited to add, 2023-11-12:*

Following up on Marko Topolnik's comment, I have a structure in my code that looks somewhat like this:

```
class Foo {
  val cache : Array<Sequence<stuff>> = Array(somesize) { emptySequence<stuff> }
  val scope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default)

  fun doStuff(d : Int): Sequence<stuff> {
    runBlocking(Dispatchers.Default) {
      if(cache[d].none()) {
        val stuffJob = async {
          somecollection.parMapNotNull { doSomethingExpensive }
            .map { convertresult }
            .sorted()
            .asSequence()
        }
        cache[d] = stuffJob.await()
      }
    }
    return cache[d]
  }
}
```

As long as I don't care at all about JS, this seems to actually work. But part of my reasons for picking Kotlin in the first place *was* the multi-platform support. If I write this with `scope.launch` instead of `runBlocking`, then nothing returns.

Elsewhere in the library, I'm using `runBlocking` to allow me to juggle a mutex to write to a caching data structure in stuff that gets called in the `doSomethingExpensive` here.

Wherever I turn, it looks like in order to use `launch` I need to already be in a coroutine, and the thing to use to transition into or out of a coroutine context is to use `runBlocking` - except then the code is no longer multi-platform.

I tried doing something like:

```
class Foo {
  val cache : Array<Sequence<stuff>> = Array(somesize) { emptySequence<stuff> }
  val scope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default)

  fun doStuff(d : Int): Sequence<stuff> {
    scope.launch(Dispatchers.Default) {
      if(cache[d].none()) {
        val stuffJob = async {
          somecollection.parMapNotNull { doSomethingExpensive }
            .map { convertresult }
            .sorted()
            .asSequence()
        }
        cache[d] = stuffJob.await()
      }
    }.join()
    return cache[d]
  }
}
```

But I'm not allowed to use `join` if I'm not in a coroutine context already, so I can't use it to wait for my parallel jobs to finish before compiling and returning the results.

I also tried doing something like:

```
class Foo {
  val cache : Array<Sequence<stuff>> = Array(somesize) { emptySequence<stuff> }
  val scope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default)

  fun doStuff(d : Int): Sequence<stuff> {
    scope.launch(Dispatchers.Default) {
      if(cache[d].none()) {
        val stuffJob = async {
          somecollection.parMapNotNull { doSomethingExpensive }
            .map { convertresult }
            .sorted()
            .asSequence()
        }
        cache[d] = stuffJob.await()
      }
    }
    while(cache[d].none()) { }
    return cache[d]
  }
}
```

But running this to test things out on the JVM (my known working platform) it seems to go into an infinite loop, spending a LOT more time on the test code than before.

Comment: `runBlocking` makes no sense for JS, where no code is allowed to block the thread. Try using `launch` instead.